# Are the two values same in postgresql jsonb type?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

In the two records in the screenshot, `Id` in the first record is `12498`, another one is `12498`, my question is are they same(type and value)?

It is updated by `jsonb_set likt jsonb_set(jsondoc_, '{"Id"}',to_jsonb(pkid_))`

[image: click the link to see the pic]

Comment: Your screen shot is hard to read, but it looks like the first value is a number while the second is a string `{"id": 12498}` vs. `{"Id": "12498"}`

Comment: thx @a_horse_with_no_name! actually i think they are all jsonb types, it seems postgresql does not provide a way to update the value to 12498( without "") per jsonb_set using a dynamic parameter

Comment: use jsonb_set(jsondoc_, '{"Id"}',to_jsonb(pkid_::int)) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not:

```
SELECT JSONB '{"id": 12498}' = JSONB '{"id": 12498}';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

SELECT JSONB '{"id": 12498}' = JSONB '{"id": "12498"}';

 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: is 12498 mapped to an int type? "12498" mapped to a text type? how can i update the value as 12498( without "") in jsonb

Comment: SImple: use `to_jsonb(12498)` as the replacement.

Comment: got it, thx! use jsonb_set(jsondoc_, '{"Id"}',to_jsonb(pkid_::int)) instead.